# Blower problem on central unit

Tags: blower

Just installed a new "smart" thermostat. The fan works on both the heating and cool setting when it is on auto. When I set it to the run position I get nothing. Is there a wiring issue?

Comment: What brand of thermostat do you have?

Comment: What are the brand & model of both the thermostat and furnace?

Comment: Yes, what make and model are your thermostat and furnace/air-handler?

Comment: It is a Honeywell RTH9585WF and the central heat is an old Borg Warner system

Comment: What wires do you have running from the air handler to the thermostat?

Comment: 5 wires, Red-R, White-W, Green-G, Yellow-Y and Blue-C